# How to change the date format in Ubuntu 10.04?

Tags: ubuntu

I'm using Ubuntu, but I cannot change the date from the format mm/dd/yyyy to dd/mm/yyyy.

Where can I change this setting?

Comment: Please mention where you are seeing the wrong format. Many programs in Ubuntu will show the date, not all use the same format.

Comment: Here's [a link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/43999/how-to-change-the-date-format) u can try and it's perfect.

Answer (score 2):

The time format is dependent on your *locale*, which is a regional setting you can change. You can either:

- modify /etc/environment and set LC_TIME to a locale which has this time format
- create a new locale

See [this article](http://ccollins.wordpress.com/2009/01/06/how-to-change-date-formats-on-ubuntu/) for more details.